# Get the users location with ipaddress in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

I want to get the users location parameters in my Angularjs app like Country, city, state, postalcode etc based on the ip address.

Comment: Are you using C# in some way to generate your client script, or why have you tagged this C#?

Comment: it can be in c#, jquery or angular

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.freegeoip.net/ They provide a service where you can look up the geolocation of an IP, using the clients IP if none has been specified.